# Custom checkboxes move slightly when selected

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I modified the checkboxes in my project to look more aligned with the rest of the design but I have a problem: whenever selected the label of the checkbox moves slightly.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none !important;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label:before {
  position: relative;
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  top: 4px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
  position: relative;
  content: "✔";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  top: 4px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<label>Click to accept</label>
```

Here's the result:

[image]

And here's what happens if I select it:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Glad you posted this. I show real check-boxes but at larger size, and they jump in FireFox one time when moving close to them after the page first loads. After that they are fine. I never could figure it out. I have a label and the input separately and in a parent div. Adding flex to the div solved it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nowadays and for awhile you can fix this if you set the parent to `display:flex`

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none !important;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  /* just to vertically the text with the box */
  align-items: center
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  content: "✔";
  /* just to center inside the box */
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="checkbox" />
<label for="input">Click to accept</label>
```

#### OLD ANSWER

To fix the "moving" you need to:

- set `vertical-align: some value` in `label::before`  I have choose `bottom`.

And to align the "✔" (in case it doesn't - snippet isn't), you need to:

- add `text-align:center` and `line-height:22px` (same as the `height`) in `:checked+label::before`

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none !important;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label::before {
  position: relative;
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  top: 4px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  content: "✔";
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="checkbox" />
<label for="input">Click to accept</label>
```

---

NB: In both answers I removed duplicated properties and you're missing the `for` attribute in `label` to match `id` in input, otherwise you can't click in the pseudo `checkbox`, only in the `label`

Answer (score 0):

I have used a flexbox for the label to align the items vertically. Adding `text-align:center` when the checkbox is checked, ensures the marker is horizontally centered.

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label:before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
  content: "✔";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="accept" />
<label for="accept">Click to accept</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see another way here.

See below working example:

```css
/*--CSS--*/
 

   

 input[type="checkbox"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    user-select: text;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 1px;
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 25px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:after {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    top:0;
}
 input[type="checkbox"]:before {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    top:0;
    opactity:0;
}
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    height: 5px;
    border-color: #009688;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 12px;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:focus{outline:0;}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label>Click to accept</label>
```

Answer (score -3):

you can try this, this is working

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
      position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
        position: relative;
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    top: 4px;
    margin: -8px 10px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
     content: "✔";
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 22px;
  }
```

```html
 <input type="checkbox"/>
 <label>Click to accept</label>
```